# While converting from NFA to DFA why 2^n states

Tags: finite-automata

folks.

Hope you all doing well. I have a question regarding to the topic Equivalence of NFA and DFAs.

While converting from NFA to DFA why we always say we'll have 2^n states, and should it be always 2^n ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you read that?  Who says you'll have 2^n states?  Can you provide a quotation, citation, excerpt from where you read that?  What research have you done?  There are multiple questions about this on this site; have you searched (using the search bar in the upper-right) to look for previous questions?

Comment: We have the rule that Q' = 2^Q right? that's what I meant.